# How to align Navigation Menu to center?

Tags: html, css

I need help to align my website's nav menu to center.

Here is my code. What's wrong with it? It does not align the menu to the center.

HTML

```
<div class="menu_nav">
    <ul style="font-family:Ubuntu">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="activities.html">Activities</a></li>
        <li><a href="games.html">Games</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu_nav {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.menu_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
.menu_nav ul li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;

}
.menu_nav ul li a {
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:35px 50px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    font-size:20px;
}
```

Comment: did you try `margin-left:auto;` and `margin-right:auto;` for `.menu_nav`

Comment: *What's wrong with that?* Almost everything, you didn't set any specific width on navigation. What do you exactly want to do?

Comment: I want it to align it to the centre. It happens when I specify width and set margin to 0. But it affects on different screen sizes. On bigger screens it does not align to centre, it is shifted to left on bigger screens and when I adjust the width for the bigger screen it shifts to right a bit.

Comment: margin-left:auto; and margin-right:auto; for .menu_nav does not affect it.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing **text-align:center**.

```
.menu_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/84exq/

Comment: it does not affect its alignment

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `margin: auto` to center something, you need to define the width of the element you are centering. You can define it in pixels, points (pt), em, or percentage values. So to fix it, you should use this bit of CSS:

```
.menu_nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 85%;
}
```

Also, to display the links inline, use the `display: inline;` property on the `li` elements and remove the `display: block` property from the `a` elements:

```
.menu_nav ul li {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 auto;
    display: inline;
}
```

jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RLUWc/1/): note that I define the width of the surrounding `div` but still define the width of the `ul` that contains the navigation.

Comment: I know that I have to to define the width of the element with which I have to use margin: auto ... I need it to work on different screens and it does not centralise on different sizes of screen.